# Draw rounded corner line in ImageDraw python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

[image]

How to draw rounded corner line in ImageDraw?

I can draw with

```
draw.line((x, y, x1, y1), width=4)
```

But the lines corner aren't rounded and they are straight flat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The graphics drawing primitives in PIL/Pillow are very basic and won't do nice bevels, meters, anti-aliasing and rounded edges like dedicated graphics drawing packages like [pycairo](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/) ([tutorial and examples](http://cairographics.org/tutorial/)).

That being said, you can emulate rounded edges on lines by drawing circles on the line ends:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.new("RGB", (640, 240))
dr = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

def circle(draw, center, radius, fill):
    dr.ellipse((center[0] - radius + 1, center[1] - radius + 1, center[0] + radius - 1, center[1] + radius - 1), fill=fill, outline=None)

W = 40
COLOR = (255, 255, 255)

coords = (40, 40, 600, 200)

dr.line(coords, width=W, fill=COLOR)
circle(dr, (coords[0], coords[1]), W / 2, COLOR)
circle(dr, (coords[2], coords[3]), W / 2, COLOR)

im.show()
```